# Is there a tangible countable model of set theory

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, axioms

ZFC or NBG set theory have a countable model by Löwenheim-Skolem. But I never found an example of one with real tangible sets. Of course I do not look for a consistency proof.
I am seeking to see how countably many objects can span an uncountable universe.
I fancy myself to came across such a countable model of NBG (lets call it $\mathcal{D}$) and want to know, whether something similar is already well known.
This is the idea:

1. Take enough axioms of NBG $\Delta=\{ext, set, pair, inf, union, power, subst, reg\}$
2. Build equivalence classes of the formulars of NBG language with one free parameter. $\varphi \equiv \psi \leftrightarrow \Delta \models \forall x \varphi(x) = \psi(x)$
3. Make these equivalence classes $[\varphi]$ the objects of the domain.
4. Ext would read $\Delta \models (\forall x \;x \in [\varphi] \leftrightarrow \mathcal{M}(x) \land \varphi(x))$ with $\mathcal{M}(x)$ being the unary relation 'x is a set'

I do not understand yet, why incompleteness is an issue. If $\varphi \equiv \psi$ is logically independent it means, that for two classes A,B A=B is independent. But this is similar to CH.

A few more examples:
$\emptyset = [ x \neq x]$
$\varphi_\omega:=\forall v \big(\emptyset \in v \land \forall u \big( (u \in v) \rightarrow (u \cup \{u\}) \in v \big) \, \big)\rightarrow x \in v $
$\omega = [\varphi_\omega]$
Inf reads: $\mathcal{M}(\omega)\land \omega \neq \emptyset$
Because of Reg: $[x \in x] \equiv \emptyset$
If I did not make a mortifying mistake this gives a nice countable model of NBG-AC. And no: neither $\epsilon$ nor $\mathcal{M}(x)$ are decidable.
The model is also canonically embedded as a submodel into any model of NBG, but it is not transitive.
If you are interested you can find the painstaking proofs here: [A countable Model of Set theory](https://www.heydorn.site/.cm4all/uproc.php/0/ACountableModel-12.pdf?cdp=a&_=189afe283c8)

Comment: It heavily depends on the meaning of being tangible, but if you mean being computable, then the answer is negative. ([See Hamkins' answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/12434/48041) for its proof.)

Comment: Thanks very much. With tangible I meant, that I could define the domain of the model as a 'class' of mathematical objects.

Comment: I mean, if it's a countable model, then the domain might as well be $\omega$...

Comment: Then do you mean being tangible by a kind of 'definability from the inside?', like we can define $L$ or $\mathrm{HOD}$ from $\mathsf{ZFC}$? Well, if there is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then we can find the minimal transitive model, which is of the form $L_\alpha$. (But I don't think this is what you want.)

Comment: thks, have put more specifics to the question

Comment: The new edit is unclear. What is the relevant equivalence relation? If it's just provable equality, this **doesn't** work since NBG is not complete (remember the key "complete-the-theory" step in Godel's completeness theorem), unless you're willing to settle for a *Boolean-valued* model which isn't really the same thing. Also, clicking your link gave a security warning.

Comment: Good to think about your comment, put more details in. Also link is improved.

Answer (score 5):

There's a pretty good reason that no "easily-visualizable" model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ exists: since (we hope) $\mathsf{ZFC}$ captures at least "core mathematical reasoning," a truly simple process for building a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ would itself be something that could be carried out and verified in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and this would contradict [Godel's second incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) *(see also [Jech's proof](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9204207.pdf) for finitely-axiomatizable set theories - while $\mathsf{ZFC}$ isn't finitely axiomatizable it has a conservative extension which is, namely $\mathsf{NBG}$, so Jech's argument still applies)*.

Put another way, if we **did** have a "simple" model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ at hand, that would be good evidence that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is **not enough** to capture as much of mathematics as we want it to.

Of course, the above is subjective. Here are some concrete observations:

- No model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is computable (as noted in the comments above). On the other hand, looking at computability-theoretic complexity is extremely coarse: since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is a computable theory, building a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is no harder than building a nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$, and in particular is strictly simpler than the halting problem (see [this survey of Diamondstone/Dzhafarov/Soare on PA-degrees](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-51/issue-1/%CE%A0-1-0-Classes-Peano-Arithmetic-Randomness-and-Computable-Domination/10.1215/00294527-2010-009.full) for more on this).
- Admittedly, the low-complexity models constructed in the previous bulletpoint are extremely odd in many ways. For example, they are not even $\omega$-models (= their versions of the natural numbers are not isomorphic to the actual natural numbers). Indeed, if $M$ is a countable $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ then $M$ computes every hyperarithmetic set; on the other hand, the Gandy Basis Theorem (a more technical analogue of the Low Basis Theorem used implicitly in the previous bulletpoint) says that we can find such an $M$ which is still much simpler than [the "higher analogue" of the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O).
- Those models are still wild, though, in that they are ill-founded. What if we want a well-founded countable model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? Well, here the picture sharpens considerably: assuming of course that such a model exists in the first place, there is a **simplest** such model in two senses: there is a unique-up-to-unique-isomorphism $W$ with the properties that

  - $W\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ and is well-founded;
  - for every well-founded $A\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ there is a unique $\Delta_0$-elementary embedding of $W$ into $A$; and
  - given any countable well-founded $A\models\mathsf{ZFC}$, we can compute $W$ from $A$.

  Incidentally, this $W$ is just "The first level of the $L$-hierarchy satisfying $\mathsf{ZFC}$, if such exists."

Comment: Thks, still digesting ... but rephrased also the question

Comment: Thks. Put more details in. Pls give me an honest answer: Is it bullshit what I have written or something to consider?